# How can I write the output of a ModelBuilder process to my attribute table?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, modelbuilder

Using ArcGIS 10.2, I've put together a Model Builder model that counts the number of wind turbines in a buffer zone:

[image]

When I'm done, I can see how many turbines have been selected at the bottom of the attribute table panel like this:

[image]

How can I use Model Builder to capture this output (e.g., the number of turbines "1040") and save it to an existing (empty) field in my attribute table?

Comment: @Luke: I just clarified in the questions text per your request. I'd like to write the numerical value "1040" to an existing field in a shapefile attributed table.

Comment: Not so much.. there is a GetCount tool http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0017000000n7000000 which you could probably hack into a field calculation. You could do this easily in python, add it to a custom toolbox then incorporate that into your model... would that help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [Get Count](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//0017000000n7000000) and [Calculate Field](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000004m000000) tools.  Make sure the output of Get Count is a precondition for Calculate Field. The output of Get Count is passed to Calculate Field via [in-line variable substitution](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/A_quick_tour_of_using_inline_variable_substitution/002w0000001t000000/).

E.g.
[image]